# SSRS Web Service URL Export to PDF with rs:Format=PDF Parameter Not Reflecting Most Recent Data in Exported PFD Report

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, report

I am using SSRS (SQL Server Reporting Services) 2022 and trying to export a report to PDF using the Web Service URL. I am adding the parameter "rs:Format=PDF" to the URL to indicate that I want the report to be exported to PDF format.

The problem I am facing is that the exported report is not reflecting the most recent data. When I access the report through Web Service URL with out PDF Export, I can see that it has been updated with the latest data everytime. However, when I export it using the Web Service URL, the exported report is still showing the old data.
Example:
If report is pulling a customer data and I try pulling the report it gets the most recent data for the first time but when I change any information in customer data then changes are not reflected in report.

Does anyone know why this might be happening and how I can ensure that the exported report reflects the most recent data?

Reports cache settings are set to **Always run this report with the most recent data**

I have tried

- Adding other parameters like "`rs:ClearSession=true`" to the URL
- Added cache buster parameter that is different every time
- Added Following tags in Head of ReportViewer.aspx to prevent browser chache

```html
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">
```

But they haven't helped in resolving the issue.
Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: SSRS report caching does not persist beyond a service restart, so restart the service. If you're still getting cached results it must be your web browser's cache or an intermediate proxy appliance.

Comment: Thank you, @AlwaysLearning, for your helpful response. I am currently using Web Service URL calls in my web application to export reports in PDF format. Despite clearing my browser cache and adding HTML tags to prevent caching (see Edit), the issue persists. As a test, I also added a JavaScript alert to the ReportViewer.aspx page. I noticed that the alert appears when the report is opened in HTML preview, but it does not trigger when the report is directly exported to PDF. Any suggestions on how to address this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**RESOLVED**
The parameter was added in the middle of the URL intially.

However, the issue was eventually resolved by moving the `rs:ClearSession=true` parameter to the end of the URL. This change somehow fixed the issue and allowed the URL to function properly.